# How to have the panel name fit on one line when using facet_wrap in ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

When I facet the plots using plotly, it causes the panel names to overlap with the next plot below it. I want the panel names to fit in the box and not overlap with the other plots below it. I have tried to change the spacing between panels but that did not seem to work. I would rather panel name fit on one line rather than on two lines. Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

mtcars$cyl = sample(letters[1:5], 32, TRUE)
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
mtcars$gear <- as.factor(mtcars$gear)


library(magrittr)
gg_facet_nrow <- function(p){
  num_panels <- length(unique(ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]$PANEL)) # get number of panels
  num_cols <- ggplot_build(p)$layout$facet$params$ncol # get number of columns set by user
  num_rows <- wrap_dims(num_panels, ncol=num_cols)[1] # determine number of rows
}

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +geom_line()+ facet_wrap( . ~ gear,  scale = "free_y", ncol = 1 ) + theme(panel.spacing = unit(1,"cm"))
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(vars(cyl, gear), scale = "free_y", ncol = 1) + theme(panel.spacing = unit(1,"cm")) 

he <- gg_facet_nrow(p1)
he1 <- gg_facet_nrow(p2)

ggplotly(p1, height = he *300)

ggplotly(p2, height = he1 * 300)
```

Here is a picture of what I mean:
[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Does the issue have anything to do with shiny? If you make the same plot *not* in Shiny, does it still have the issue?

Comment: It still happens even when I'm not using shiny. I believe it might be because I'm using facet_wrap instead of facet_grid. Although, I feel like there should be some way to fix this problem. Basically, the 4 is the gear and a is the cyl in the photo. I'm not sure how these two things go be on one line on the panel name.

Comment: I assume then it's a plotly issue - if you make a plain `ggplot` does it work? Just trying to figure out how to make your problem **minimal**, which usually makes it easier to debug.

Comment: It's not a problem when I just use ggplot.  It seems to only happen when the plot is converted to plotly.

Comment: Would you mind extracting your code from shiny to make a **minimal** reproducible example?

Comment: It should be reproducible. I included the code above the pictures and gif. The dataset is mtcar which comes from base r. I just took a sample just to make it easier to load.

Comment: Yes, it's nicely reproducible, but it's far from **minimal**. If I were to work on it, the first thing I would do would be to make it more minimal, but since you've built it it would probably be much faster for you to do it--and also make the question more attractive for others to work on it - right now people probably won't look at this question unless they're experts at Shiny **and** Plotly. I'm pretty good at Shiny, but not great at Plotly. If you strip the Shiny out since it's irrelevant, maybe someone good at Plotly will come and solve it real quick.

Comment: I understand and have made changes to the question.